# SQL Query for table with three dates and trying to standardize year

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, count

I am trying to manipulate my data in SQLite and am still new to it.

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

Ultimately I want to return a table with this structure

```
YEAR     NET_NEW
1994     0
1995     1
1996     0
1997     2
etc
```

Ultimately, I want to group by year. Net_New will be equal to number of instances year_enforced occured in that grouped by year minus the number of instances where year_terminated occured.

**Example logic**

```
year = 2008
net_new = # of times 2008 occured in the column "year_enforced" - # of times 2008 occured in "year terminated"
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does the column `year_signed` contain all the years that you want in the results?

Comment: @forpas I believe so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 correlated subqueries:

```
select t.year,
       (select count(*) from tablename where year_enforced = t.year) -
       (select count(*) from tablename where year_terminated = t.year) as net_new
from (select distinct year_signed as year from tablename) as t
order by t.year
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but if I did I think I found an answer.
I used this data

```
status,year_signed,year_enforced,year_terminated,country_1,country_b
signed,2008,0,0,barbados,ghana
active,2004,2005,0,barbados,mauritius
active,1998,1999,0,barbados,china
active,1996,1997,0,barbados,temp
active,1996,1998,0,barbados,temp
active,1995,1997,0,barbados,temp
active,1995,1995,0,barbados,temp
active,1994,2002,0,barbados,temp
```

And the query I created was this one:

```sql
SELECT 
    year_signed - year_terminated as year,
    COUNT(year_enforced) as net_new
  FROM table_name
  GROUP by year_enforced
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unpivot and aggregate:

```
select year, sum(inc)
from (select year_signed as year, 1 as inc from t
      union all
      select year_enforced, -1 from t
     ) y
group by year;
```

Note that this ensures that all years are included in the result set, even if some years are missing "signed" or "enforced" records.